# What's Kane S. Yee who invented FDTD in Chinese?

Tags: finite-difference, computational-physics

I'm not sure if the question suits this section of StackExchange, but I think the chance to get the answer is highest here (compared with other forums). So I hope more tolerance could be shown towrad this question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand your question in the body of your post?

Comment: Please at the very least tell us what FDTD stands for

Comment: @IanBush The "Yee scheme" is a finite-difference time-domain (FDTD) scheme to solve some partial differential equations.

Comment: I second the call to clarify the question. Are you just looking for the Chinese spelling of Yee's name?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for. Just the Chinese spelling of Yee's name.

Comment: His full chinese name is 凯恩·希·贡·伊 (Kane Shee-Gong Yee).

Comment: @njuffa I doubt Chinese Stackexchange would be useful. Without a background of computational electrodynamics, the best answer there is a guess based on the pronunciation. You are correct that most probably I may get the answer from a Chinese scholar who cited his paper. I think the chance to have such a scholar here is higher :)

Comment: @Pepe Thanks for your input. Would you please provide the source? I also came across a webpage containing this Chinese name, but unfortunately the webpage seems to be translated directly by machine...

Comment: @Pu Zhang You can find it for example: [here](https://wikii.one/Kane_S._Yee#gsc.tab=0) and [here](https://upwikizh.top/wiki/Finite-difference_time-domain_method). Could be auto generated though.

Comment: @Pepe Yes, I'm afraid these two are auto generated. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I've got the answer to my own question through private communication. The Chinese name of the inventor of computational electrodynamics technique, or finite-difference time domain method, is 余树江.

Comment: Could you fill in the `native_name` field in the infobox on the Wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kane_S._Yee , so that the answer gets to Wikipedia, too? It should be a very quick edit at the top of the page. I'm a little too shy to do it myself since I don't speak a single word of Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Federico! But here's the awkward thing. Wikipedia is banned in China :) I visit it via a proxy. The edit is blocked for the IP address of the proxy. Please feel free to fill the infobox.

Comment: Oops. Sad to hear that. I'll make the edit myself then.

Comment: Thanks for doing it!

Comment: Hi. Could you please try providing a source for it and try publishing this information elsewhere to make it more "authoritative"? Currently, there's no information about Yee's Chinese name anywhere in the open literature. It means the entire Chinese literature is going to depend on this answer on Stack Exchange, which is not a reliable source.

Comment: For example, if you got his name from a researcher or university professor, try asking them to put the answer on their institution or university's home page or research blog. Or at the very least, publish it in the personal home page of your own research institution. Even better, if you (or someone you know) is going to publish a research paper on FDTD in Chinese, you can write down his name in Chinese with a footnote that says the source of the name is "personal communication". This way the information becomes citable by others.

Comment: Yee's Chinese name appears in Section 3.2 of the book "时域有限差分方法及编程技巧" translated by 余文华. A more reliable source can only be his own family :p